# How to fix 'identifier 'ACCOUNT_REQUEST_TBL' must be declared

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

an error

> **FRM-40735:** WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED trigger raised unhandled
>   exception **ORA-06502**

raises when I try to insert my fields as below. What could be the reason ?

```
DECLARE

    v_reqid NUMBER(10) := :txtreqid;
    v_branch VARCHAR2(15) := :txtbranch;
    v_acctype VARCHAR2(15) := :txtacctype;
    v_title VARCHAR2(4) := :txttitle;
    v_firstname VARCHAR2(15) := :register.txtfirstname;
    v_lastname VARCHAR2(15) := :register.TXLASTNAME;
    v_DOB DATE := :txtdob;
    v_workp NUMBER(10) := :txtworkp;
    v_hphone NUMBER(10) := :txthphone;
    v_address VARCHAR2(30) := :txtadd;
    v_state_info VARCHAR2(15) := :txtstate;
    v_hphone NUMBER(10) := :txtzip;
    v_email VARCHAR2(30) := :txtemail;
    v_status VARCHAR2(10) := :txtstatus;
    v_user_name VARCHAR2(30) := :txtun;
    v_password VARCHAR2(30) := :txtpw;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO account_request_tbl
    VALUES(v_reqid,v_branch,v_acctype,v_title,v_firstname,  v_lastname,v_DOB,v_workp, 
           v_hphone,v_address,v_state_info,v_hphone,v_email,v_status,v_user_name,v_password);

    COMMIT;
    message('You have succesfully created a new account!');
END;
```

Comment: Is the table `account_request_tbl` exists in your DB?

Comment: hello. i already found a way to fix it. I forgot to put `commit;` at the end of my db. My bad, sorry im just a beginner in oracle

Comment: So i have another problem after that when I try to input in my fields, i get an error `FRM-40735: WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED trigger raised unhandled exception ORA-06502`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the variable name are derived from the table `account_request_tbl` columns' names, define your variables' data types by using `account_request_tbl.<column_name>%type` instead. Since your issue is related with the mismatch of data types and/or precision between local variables and data types of columns :

```
DECLARE
    v_reqid      account_request_tbl.reqid%type := :txtreqid;
    v_branch     account_request_tbl.branch%type := :txtbranch;
    v_acctype    account_request_tbl.acctype%type := :txtacctype;
    v_title      account_request_tbl.title%type := :txttitle;
    v_firstname  account_request_tbl.firstname%type := :register.txtfirstname;
    v_lastname   account_request_tbl.lastname%type := :register.TXLASTNAME;
    v_DOB        account_request_tbl.dob%type := :txtdob;
    v_workp      account_request_tbl.workp%type := :txtworkp;
    v_hphone     account_request_tbl.hphone%type := :txthphone;
    v_address    account_request_tbl.address%type := :txtadd;
    v_state_info account_request_tbl.state_info%type := :txtstate;
    v_email      account_request_tbl.email%type := :txtemail;
    v_status     account_request_tbl.status%type := :txtstatus;
    v_user_name  account_request_tbl.user_name%type := :txtun;
    v_password   account_request_tbl.password%type := :txtpw;
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO account_request_tbl(reqid,branch,acctype,title,firstname,lastname,dob,workp,
               hphone, address, state_info, email, status, user_name, password )
   VALUES(v_reqid,v_branch,v_acctype,v_title,v_firstname,  v_lastname,v_DOB,v_workp,              
          v_hphone,v_address,v_state_info,v_email,v_status,v_user_name,
          v_password);

   IF SQL%ROWCOUNT > 0 THEN 
     COMMIT;
     message('You have succesfully created a new account!');
   ELSE
     ROLLBACK;
     message('Unfortunately, you couldn''t create a new account !!!');
   END IF; 
END;
```

*The reson for the error might vary such as the field `:txtadd`'s  length doesn't fit for `VARCHAR2(30)`, or the value in `:txtreqid` field is of string type .. etc.*
Indeed no need to declare variables explicitly, direct substitution within the `INSERT` statement is enough( *thanks @AndyDan* ) as

```
INSERT INTO account_request_tbl(reqid,branch,acctype,title,firstname,lastname,dob,workp,
            hphone, address, state_info, email, status, user_name, password )
VALUES(:txtreqid,:txtbranch,:txtacctype,:txttitle,:register.txtfirstname,  
       :register.txlastname, :txtdob, :txtworkp,:txthphone, :txtadd, :txtstate,:txtemail,
       :txtstatus, :txtun, :txtpw);
```

Comment: Why even declare variables?  Just use the fields directly in the INSERT statement.